# Android, Trouble with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, fragment

Have got a trouble with the use of startActivityForResult into a fragment.

So i've got a main activity which handle a stack of fragments.

On the last fragment i launch the code bellow which work well

```
        Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );

    startActivityForResult ( Intent.createChooser ( intent, "Le titre" ), REQUEST_CODE_CHOIX_PHOTO_MEMBRE_FAMILLE );
```

When i choose a picture, the intent is closed and the onActivityResult in my fragment is call and do the job.

Everything seems right? 
Yes but when onActivityResult is call, my app pops all my stack and the fisrt fragment is shown!

So i there is a way to keep the last fragment when i do a startActivityForResult?

Thanks
Regards
Alexandre

Comment: Show your onActivityResult method and how you navigate between fragments

Comment: I think you have some code in **onActivityResult** method which will be calling first fragment to show. Post  **onActivityResult**  code.